# angular ng-class javascript conditions on modal string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-class

Am trying to apply style class to based on the modal value.

I am trying to add glyphicons icons based the value in the modal. But I struggle to get that work. Below is the code I use.

```
<span ng-class="{glyphicon:'true','glyphicon-search':(menu.name.indexOf('search')!=-1),'glyphicon-home':(menu.name.indexOf('home')!=-1)}"></span>{{menu.name}}</a>
```

Let me know what is the issue, or should I not use the index of mehtod in the angular expressions

Comment: I just did a test using your code and the class is properly populating. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/ybcr6/). What issue are you facing?

Comment: It populates for all menu.name values that is the problem, search should be coming only when menu.name is search and home should come only when the menu.name is home

Comment: I'm still not sure I am 100% following you, [here is an updated fiddle showing a repeater with `home`, `search` and `about` as sample names.](http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/ybcr6/2/)

Comment: I think I understand now, sounds like you might either want an `ng-if` in there to get rid of the span it is not a icon friendly name. Or you could merge the `glyphicon` class into both search and home: i.e. `'glyphicon glyphicon-search':(menu.name.indexOf('search')!=-1)` and drop `glyphicon:'true'` otherwise every element will have that class

Comment: Thanks.. I got the issue. The problem is, the menu.name has capital letters hence I got false always, now replaced with menu.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('search') it works fine now..